# How can I dynamically change the text of many textboxes?

Tags: c#, forms

This is a piece of the code i have done but i want to make it shorter.

```
textBox0.Text = array[0];
textBox1.Text = array[1];
textBox2.Text = array[2];
textBox3.Text = array[3];
textBox4.Text = array[4];
....
```

This is how i want it :

```
int a = 0;
for(int N=0; N++; N<5)
        textboxN.text = array[a];
        a++;
```

Comment: Put your textBox* objects in a list and then iterate on this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the textboxes have a common container or parent, like a Panel or GroupBox control, you can do this:

```
 TextBox[] textBoxes = container.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

And then later:

```
for(int N = 0; N < array.Length; N++)
{
    textbox[N].Text = array[N];
}
```

Note the container can even be your form, but in this case you must make sure you don't have an other TextBox controls on the form. That's why something like a borderless panel might be useful here; it gives you a logical section on the form to keep these fields separate in a way that can be invisible to the user.

Comment: I have a groupbox but i don't know how to make it common for textboxes.

Comment: You put the textbox controls in the groupbox, instead of directly on the form.

Comment: Sorry but i still dont understand. I have some textboxes and a groupbox in the form. To use the code you wrote me I need to make the groupbox common to the textboxes. How can i do it?

Comment: In the forms designer, you put the textboxes inside the groupbox.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() {textBox0, textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
for(int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    textBoxes[i].Text = array[i];
}
```

You put the text boxes into a list and then go through them and set the values.
Here is that as a one-liner

```
textBoxes.Foreach(x => x.Text = array[textBoxes.IndexOf(x)]);
```

Comment: You should write: `i < textBoxes.Count`

Comment: oh sorry I forgot

Comment: Not a fan of the second option. The `for` loop syntax is older and longer, but it's linear time. The `ForEach()` option, when combined with `IndexOf()`, is at least N log(N), if not worse. I know it's a small "N", but it still bothers me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var textBoxList = new List<Control>();
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
    {
        textBoxList.Add(control as Control);
    }
}

textBoxList = textBoxList.OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < textBoxList.Count; i++)
{
    textBoxList[i].Text = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but it makes some sense if you have dozens textboxes

```
var maxIndex=array.length;
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    var textBox = control as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null && textBox.Name.Substring(0,6)=="textBox")
    {
         int number;
         var value = textBox.Name.Substring(7));
         var success = int.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (success && number < maxIndex))
         {
          textBox.Text=array[number];
         }
    }
}
```